# Inserting datetime into MSSQL table

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to insert some datetime to a table I created using:

```
insert into dbo.Table(Id, StartTime, StopTime) values('1',Convert(datetime, '2023-02-14 01:41:24', 113),null)
```

Of course stop time is nullable, but it seems I have run into a problem, converter for database gives me

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

And basically I am stuck, what could be the issue here?
Also can I set some pattern on datetime column so i do not need to convert that value each time?
And if not is there a way to tell that I tell server some sort of default format like:

```
Convert(datetime, '2023-02-14 01:41:24', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss')
```

Comment: Use an unambiguous format, such as `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss` or `yyyyMMdd hh:mm:ss` and then you don't need an explicit `CONVERT`. The style you've defined, `113`, is the format "`dd mon yyyy hh:mi:ss:mmm`" and your string is clearly not in that format.

Comment: What date is `2023-28-14` supposed to be? There are only 12 months and 14 and 28 are both greater than that

Comment: `2023-28-14` is not a valid date in any calendar I know.

Comment: The [CONVERT documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) contains the valid format strings. Never mind the invalid string, 113 is the wrong style too. It's `dd mon yyyy hh:mi:ss:mmm`. Instead of trying to parse strings, use date-typed parameters and pass the data as actual dates from the client, not strings. If you absolutely have to hard-code the values use an unambiguous format

Comment: Aye unambiguous format worked like a charm :)

Comment: Only if you also fixed the bad data. And that's *not* the correct solution if the data comes from the client. Parameterized queries are easier, safer and faster

Comment: And I will do that